# We have $b=Ax$. Under what conditions on $A$ we can choose $x$ such that $b$ becomes sufficiently negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

We have a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ where $m>n$ ($m$ can be way much larger than $n$). The problem is to choose a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that every component of $b=Ax\in\mathbb{R}^m$ can be made as negative as possible. That is for any given vector $c\in\mathbb{R}^m$, we can choose $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax<c$ component wise.

Since the range space of $A$ cannot have a dimension larger than $n$, the rows of $A$ needs to satisfy some conditions so that every component of $Ax$ can be made as negative as possible.

When $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}\\ a_{21}\end{bmatrix}$, the condition is that $a_{11}$ and $a_{22}$ have the same sign. When the dimension goes higher, I was wondering what the conditions are. Is there a theorem/result for general cases?

Comment: What do you mean?  Why not take $x = 0$, which makes every component of $Ax$ equal to $0$?

Comment: Please a condition to $x$ (such as $||x|| = 1$) to your post.

Comment: Your statement of the problem is unclear Are you trying to minimize the absolute value of the largest (in absolute value) component of $Ax$?

Comment: I have modified the question to make it more clear.

Comment: If $Ax <0$ component wise, then $A(\alpha x) = \alpha Ax \ll 0$ for $\alpha\to \infty$. So you just need $x$ such that $Ax <0$.

Comment: The question is imprecise. "Sufficiently negative" brings no information and "as negative as possible" is always achieved !

Comment: You need the column space to intersect the negative orthant.

Comment: @MichaelBurr : very thorough.

Comment: @Surb Yes. You are right. Then the question becomes under what conditions on $A$ there always exists $x$ such that $Ax<0$ component wise.

Comment: @YHH Indeed, and if I remember correctly there is an answer to this question in the book "Nonnegative Matrices in the Mathematical Sciences " of Berman and Plemmons. Exercise (3.7) [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=TaXiBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA63&hl=fr&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false) is probably helpful.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks for your insights. Yes. We need the range space to intersect the negative orthant. That is the intersection between them is not empty. The problem then becomes given a matrix $A$, how to check if its range space intersects the negative orphant or not.

Comment: @Surb Thanks for the resources. I will check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An equivalent condition is that the only nonnegative vector in the null space of $A^T$ is $0$. See [Gordan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas'_lemma#Further_implications).

In practice, you can use linear programming software to decide if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks. Very nice theorem. Truely helpful.